# Is there a way to make a loop with multiple conditions? c#

Tags: c#

I made a simple program that asks the user for their name, then a number that is 1 or 2 and then writes their name and number to the console.

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to make it so that the user can only enter the numbers 1 or 2 in a single loop (I am assuming there is something obvious I am missing).

Code:

```
        string strName;
        string strNumber;
        int intNumber;

        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        strName = Console.ReadLine();        

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number (1 or 2)");
        strNumber = Console.ReadLine();
       bool test = int.TryParse(strNumber, out intNumber);

         while (intNumber >2)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number (1 or 2)");
            strNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(strNumber, out intNumber);
        }
        while (intNumber < 1)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number (1 or 2)");
            strNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(strNumber, out intNumber);
        }
        while (test == false)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number (1 or 2)");
            strNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(strNumber, out intNumber);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Welcome, your name is "+ strName+ " your number is " + intNumber);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

As you can see from the code above I have 3 separate loops, which creates a problem since they run from top to bottom and once they have been passed they no longer loop, so the user could enter: 10, f and then 7 and the program would be OK with that.

If there is another more simple way of doing what I want could you tell me please.

-Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the `if` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
int response = 0;

while (response != 1 && response != 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number (1 or 2)");
    var strNumber = Console.ReadLine();
    int intNumber;
    if (int.TryParse(strNumber.Trim(), out intNumber))
    {
        response = intNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will loop forever. `response` will always be not equal to either 1 or 2.

Comment: oops my bad.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine all those while loops...

```
while (intNumber < 1 || intNumber > 2 || ...)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can add as many conditions as you wish for a loop**. I'm not sure I've got what logic you supposed to implement hope this helps:

```
        string nameStr = String.Empty;
        string numberStr = String.Empty;
        int parsedNumber = 0;
        bool continueLoop = true;
        bool isParsed = true;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
                nameStr = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number (1 or 2)");
                numberStr = Console.ReadLine();
                isParsed = int.TryParse(numberStr, out parsedNumber);
                if (parsedNumber > 2)
                {
                    ///todo: Implement your Logic here!
                }
                else if (parsedNumber < 1)
                {
                    ///todo: Implement your Logic here!
                }
                else
                {
                    ///todo: Implement your Logic here!                        
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                continueLoop = false;
            }
        } while (isParsed && continueLoop);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use a `FOR loop` with multiple conditions, below is an example

```
for(int i=0,j=0;i<5&& j>-5;i++,j--){
//Do something
}
```